# Tracking relative mouse position without a mousemove event

Tags: javascript, css, events, css-transforms

I need to track mouse position relative to a `<canvas>` element in my app. Currently, I have a `mousemove` event listener attached to the `<canvas>` that updates my mouse position whenever it fires, using `offsetX`/`offsetY` when available, or `layerX`/`layerY` when the `offsetX/Y` is not available. Using `offsetX/Y` or `layerX/Y` gives me mouse coordinates relative to my `<canvas>`, which is exactly what I want. As my app works its magic, various CSS 3d transformations get applied to the `<canvas>`, and even when `<canvas>` is very transformed, `offsetX/Y` still gives me accurate coordinates within the `<canvas>`'s local, transformed coordinate-space.

That's kind of confusing, so I'll try stating an example. If my `<canvas>` is 100px in both width and height, and is located at (0,0) relative to the browser viewport, and I click at (50,50) (in viewport coords), that corresponds to (50,50) in my `<canvas>`, and 50 is the value that is (correctly) returned via `offsetX` and `offsetY`. If I then apply `transform: translate3d(20px,20px,0px)` to my `<canvas>` and click at (50,50) (in viewport coords), since my canvas has been shifted 20px down and 20px to the right, that actually corresponds to (30,30) relative to the `<canvas>`, and 30 is the value that is (correctly) returned via `offsetX` and `offsetY`.

The problem I'm facing is what to do when the user is not physically moving the mouse, yet the `<canvas>` is being transformed. I'm only updating the position of the mouse on `mousemove` events, so what do I do when there is no `mousemove`?

For example. My mouse is positioned at (50,50) and no transformations are applied to the `<canvas>`. My `this.mouseX` and `this.mouseY` are both equal to 50; they were saved at the final `mousemove` event when I moved the mouse to (50,50). Without moving the mouse at all, I apply the above transformation (`transform: translate3d(20px,20px,0px)`) to my `<canvas>`. Now, I need `this.mouseX` and `this.mouseY` to each be equal to 30, as that is my mouse's new position relative to the current transformation of `<canvas>`. But `this.mouseX` and `this.mouseY` are still equal to 50. Since I never moved the mouse, there was no `mousemove` event fired, and those saved coords never got updated.

How can I deal with this? I thought about creating a new jQuery event, manually assigning some properties (`pageX` and `pageY`?) based on my old/previous mouse position, and then triggering that event, but I don't think that's going to cause the browser to recalculate the `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties. I've also been thinking about taking the known old/previous mouse position and multiplying it by my transformation matrix, but that's going to get real complicated since my mouse coordinates are in 2d-space, but the transformations I'm applying to `<canvas>` are all 3d transformations.

I guess really, what I want to do is take my known 2d page position and raycast it into the 3d space and find out where I'm hitting the transformed `<canvas>`, all in javascript (jQuery is available).

Is this possible? Does this even make sense?

Comment: If you want to get "new" mouse coordinates without the mouse being moved - then I think you'll have to take your "old" coordinates (from the last mousemove event), and "apply" the transformation to those values yourself to calculate what the correct "new" coordinates should be.

Comment: @CBroe I was really hoping to avoid that, but you might be right ...

Answer (score 1):

Works in all browsers

```
 var mouseX=0;
 var mouseY=0;
 var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 document.onmousemove = function(e) {
      mouseX=e.clientX-rect.left;
      mouseY=e.clientY-rect.top;
};
function updateCoords() {
      mouseX=e.clientX-mouseX;
      mouseY=e.clientY-mouseY;
      setTimeout(updatecoords,10);
}
```

Now we can call `updateCoords()` function once to repeatedly check for new position.

```
 updateCoords();
```

You can add your code inside the `updateCoords()` function and it will be executed each 10 milliseconds

Concept: `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables get updated on `mousemove` event, and also get updated when there is any change in the canvas position.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to refresh your mouseposition-values even if you don't move your mouse. You should try something like this:

```
var event = '';
var counter = 1;

$(function(e){
    event = e;
    window.setInterval(refresh, 10);
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    event = e;
    refresh;
});

function refresh(){
    counter++;
    $('#mousepos').val("event.pageX: " + event.pageX + ", event.pageY: " + event.pageY + ", counter: " + counter)
}
```

The counter is just for visualisation of the refresh. You can set the interval to everything you want (10 = 10ms = 0.01s) Just move everything from your .mousemove() event into this refresh() function and call it properly and your mouse position should update even if you don't move your mouse.

Look at this fiddle for a life example: http://jsfiddle.net/82cmxw8L/1

**EDIT:**

Because my fiddle didn't work for the asker, i updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/82cmxw8L/8/

New is, that the mouseposition is now set every 0.1 Second, no matter what, rather than being updated only when the mouse moves.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately, it looks like this won't quite work for my purposes. I edited your jsfiddle a bit to test it out. I added a box which slides to the right when you hover over it, and attached the event to that box instead of the document, and when you hover over the box and it slides, you can see that the offsetX and offsetY values (mouse position relative to the div rather than the page) are NOT being updated until you actually do move the mouse.

Comment: I updated my answer. It should now work as you expected.